# Need Help in understanding this java program

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to understand this wordsearch program 
http://kosbie.net/cmu/spring-07/15-111/handouts/java/WordSearch.java

I see the author has used drow and dcol along with the offset to find whether we are going off the board or not. I am not understanding this part.

```
public static void findWord(String word, int row, int col) {
for (int drow=-1; drow<=1; drow++)
    for (int dcol=-1; dcol<=1; dcol++)
        findWord(word,row,col,drow,dcol);
}

public static void findWord(String word, int row, int col, int drow, int dcol) {
int rows = getRows();
int cols = getCols();
for (int offset=0; offset<word.length(); offset++) {
    int targetRow = row + offset*drow;
    int targetCol = col + offset*dcol;
    if ((targetRow < 0) ||
            (targetRow >= rows) ||
            (targetCol < 0) ||
            (targetCol >= cols))
        // we're off the board, no match
        return;
    char boardChar = board.get(targetRow).charAt(targetCol);
    char wordChar  = word.charAt(offset);
    if (boardChar != wordChar)
        // mismatch, so we're done
        return;
}
System.out.printf("%s at %d,%d direction %d,%d\n",
        word, row, col, drow, dcol);
}
```

why is the loop running from -1 to 1. I am not understanding the offset and target calculation. I saw a similar post in topcoder where the author talks about "Handling Grid representations"

http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=698352&start=0&mc=5

Can someone please help me in understanding this? Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Why is it tagged [tag:c#] and not [tag:java]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drow` and `dcol` are the directions. There are 9 possible directions and the loops iterate through all of them.

`targetRow` and `targetCol` are calculated by starting at `col` and `row` and moving in one direction by `offset` units.

For example:

if `drow` is 1 and `dcol` is 0. That means move down.

`row + 1 * offset` would find the row `offset` units below the current one.

`col + 0 * offset` would keep the col as it is.